# Laravel logging in multiple channels when it shouldn't

Tags: laravel

I've a Laravel application misbehaving.
It's logging into two different channels and I don't understand why.
In the logfile, I have those lines :

```
    [2024-02-21 13:05:47] local.INFO: UserDao.getByMatricule C182697 on 10.48.86.7  
    [2024-02-21 13:05:47] local.INFO: UserDao.getByMatricule C182697 on 10.48.86.7  
    [2024-02-21 13:05:47] local.INFO: UserDao.getByMatricule C182697 on 10.48.86.7  
    [2024-02-21 13:05:47] local.INFO: UserDao.getByMatricule C182697 on 10.48.86.7  
    [2024-02-21 13:05:47] production.INFO: UserDao.getByMatricule C182697 on 10.48.86.7  
    [2024-02-21 13:05:47] production.INFO: UserDao.getByMatricule C182697 on 10.48.86.7
```

The logging code is this :

```
    Log::info('UserDao.getByMatricule ' . $matricule . ' on ' . $ip);
```

As you can see, the channel, if I understand well, changes in the middle of the logging, from local to production.
In the config/logging.php, i see no trace of 'local' or 'production'.

The application is configured in .env file with :

```
    APP_NAME=Laravel  
    APP_ENV=local  
    APP_DEBUG=false  
    APP_URL=http://localhost  
    LOG_CHANNEL=stack  
    LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null  
    LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Additional info :

- Laravel version 10.13.5
- There is 2 servers, one for production, one for test.
  Both shares the same code, except for database credentials.
  Rest of the .env file is the same, including APP_ENV and APP_KEY
- config/app.php and config/logging.php are the same on both servers
  'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production')
- The application has been in production for several years, and this happens rarely (70 times on 557.000 lines of log)
- Both production and test servers are behind a reverse proxy
- I suspect an environnment mismatch because I've been called by a user who was seeing things he didn't have the rights to see.

The questions are:

- How can laravel output to two differents channels given that configuration ?
- How are those channels configured ?

EDIT:
conf/logging.php:

```
<?php

use Monolog\Handler\NullHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler;
use Monolog\Processor\PsrLogMessageProcessor;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Log Channel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option defines the default log channel that gets used when writing
    | messages to the logs. The name specified in this option should match
    | one of the channels defined in the "channels" configuration array.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Deprecations Log Channel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the log channel that should be used to log warnings
    | regarding deprecated PHP and library features. This allows you to get
    | your application ready for upcoming major versions of dependencies.
    |
    */

    'deprecations' => [
        'channel' => env('LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL', 'null'),
        'trace' => false,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log Channels
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log channels for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Drivers: "single", "daily", "slack", "syslog",
    |                    "errorlog", "monolog",
    |                    "custom", "stack"
    |
    */

    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'replace_placeholders' => true,
        ],

        'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'days' => 14,
            'replace_placeholders' => true,
        ],

        'slack' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
            'username' => 'Laravel Log',
            'emoji' => ':boom:',
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'critical'),
            'replace_placeholders' => true,
        ],

        'papertrail' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'handler' => env('LOG_PAPERTRAIL_HANDLER', SyslogUdpHandler::class),
            'handler_with' => [
                'host' => env('PAPERTRAIL_URL'),
                'port' => env('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'),
                'connectionString' => 'tls://'.env('PAPERTRAIL_URL').':'.env('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'),
            ],
            'processors' => [PsrLogMessageProcessor::class],
        ],

        'stderr' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
            'formatter' => env('LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER'),
            'with' => [
                'stream' => 'php://stderr',
            ],
            'processors' => [PsrLogMessageProcessor::class],
        ],

        'syslog' => [
            'driver' => 'syslog',
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'facility' => LOG_USER,
            'replace_placeholders' => true,
        ],

        'errorlog' => [
            'driver' => 'errorlog',
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'replace_placeholders' => true,
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => NullHandler::class,
        ],

        'emergency' => [
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Can you post your `config/logging.php`?

Comment: Haven't you changed environment type with code? F.e like this: `app()['env'] = 'production';`

Comment: I haven't but actually found an interesting line of code in LogManager.php when searching for 'production' :     
protected function getFallbackChannelName()
    {
        return $this->app->bound('env') ? $this->app->environment() : 'production';
    }

Comment: @madgangmixers according to your first question, are you want a snippet to log on two different channel i.e. one can be `stack` and other will be `slack`? Am I right? If I'm right can you plz tell me is both channel will be `stack` with different `file-names` or else tell me the names of channels you want to configure.

Comment: I find that whenever I think that laravel is to blame for something, after digging deeper it's almost always the app code.

Correct me if I'm wrong, this log is from the test server? Because if it isn't then it seems to be correcting itself ( first wrong as local, then right as production ).

Another thing, are those logs in a loop or in different requests? If they are in a loop, then you're somehow editing the config value of env.

Comment: @M-Khawar i want to log to a single channel, but only the 'local' one, not 'production'

Comment: @HeliosLive the logs are from the test server, and from different requests (angular frontend)

Comment: @madgangmixers this is your problem,  "By default, Monolog is instantiated with a "channel name" that matches the current environment, such as `production` or `local`. To change this value, add a `name` option to your channel's configuration" [link here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/logging#configuring-the-channel-name) , my guess is that your `.env` changes from `production` to `local` on server and by that it logs that way. change the name to see if no more is done with production and local.

Comment: @francisco After reading that page, I believe this is the correct explanation. If you want to make an answer, I'll award the bounty.

Comment: @madgangmixers you could try to find references to env() outside configs. When configs are cached the env() returns the default value. In your case production. And when not cached, the .env value in your case local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.env` changes from `production` to `local` on the server, and by that, it logs that way. When you add the `name` to the stack, no more will have the environment because by default, Monolog is instantiated with the "channel name" that matches the current environment, such as `production` or `local`. To change this value, add a `name` option to your channel's configuration like this:

```
'stack' => [
    'driver' => 'stack',
    'name' => 'channel-name', // change this to whatever you want.
    'channels' => ['single'],
    'ignore_exceptions' => false,
],
```

The reference on the documentation is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/logging#configuring-the-channel-name).

Comment: Thank you, now I'll have to find why the environment changes in the middle, but that explains this question.